# Why does RegionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName return 3 chars for Caribbean?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, regioninfo

Trying to generate currency type seed data for an application and iterating through the CultureInfo collection of System.Globalization. I kept getting truncation errors on my insert statements until I discovered that when Caribbean comes up (listed at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as CB) a 3 character value of 029 on the TwoLetterISORegionName. I had a serious WTF moment.

Does anyone know why this happens?

To reproduce:

Instantiate the RegionInfo object for the Caribbean.

```
RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(9225);
```

Access the TwoLetterISORegionName property.
Value should be CB. Actual value is 026.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no ISO-3166 2-letter ISO Country Code based on the [ISO Website](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/english_country_names_and_code_elements.htm). The same goes for the [Wikipedia ISO 3166-1 page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2).

It is quite interesting that Carribean is listed by MSDN. Maybe this is because RegionInfo also applies to geographical regions and not only to countries, but that's just a guess.

Comment: So it's likely that it's a documentation issue rather than a framework issue. Darn. I thought my nerd cred had just gone up by virtue of finding an actual framework bug.

Comment: I'm not sure that you are wrong with your assumption. It might be misleading to try to cover both regions and countries with the same structure and provide some common methods/properties for it, with leads to some "conflicts".

Comment: I have had it verified by Microsoft that this is a documentation error. They have assured me the knowledge base will be updated to reflect that Caribbean ISO will be returned as 029 per international standard.